# median of percentages?

Tags: statistics, recreational-mathematics, education, median

I am looking to validate if my thoughts on answering the following question. The question is something I've made up / hypothetical / and may not reflect real life.

Question:

At a used car dealership 5% of sales go to cars that have a length equal to 3850 mm or less, 10% of sales go to cars that have a length equal to 3950 mm or less, 30% of sales go to cars that have a length equal to 4200 mm or less, 50% of sales go to cars that have a length equal to 4400 mm or less, 65 % of sales go to cars that have a length equal to 4600 mm or less. What which size classification of car is the median length?

Answer attempt / Reasoning:

- 5% sales go to <=3850 mm
- 10% sales go to <=3950 mm
- 30% sales go to <=4200 mm
- 50% sales go to <=4400 mm
- 65% sales go to <=4600 mm

Since there are 5 size classifications, the median would be calculating in the following manner:

Median position of the sample = (n + 1) /2, such that n in this example is the number of car size classifications.

Median position of the sample = (5 + 1) / 2 = 6 /2 = 3

Therefore the median length of car size classification would go to 30% of sales for cars that had a length equal to 4200 mm or less?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not 4400 or less? or between 4200 and 4400. The 50% point comes at an interval boundary. Definitions of quantiles differ among various textbooks. Be sure you're using the definition used in your course.

Comment: There is a sixth size "> 4600 mm", presumably with $35\%$ of sales

Comment: Thank you for your response, you have answered and confirmed my questions about my question.